# Equatable Packages does not navigate the pages properly

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class LandingPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const LandingPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocListener<LandingBloc, LandingState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state is HomeState) {
          _pageRoute(const HomePage(), context);
        } else if (state is LoginState) {
          _pageRoute(const LoginPage(), context);
        }
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Landing")),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              const Text("Landing", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30)),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () => context.read<LandingBloc>().add(LoginClick()),
                child: const Text("Login"),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () => context.read<LandingBloc>().add(HomeClick()),
                child: const Text("Home"),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _pageRoute(page, context) {
    return Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => page));
  }
}

class LandingBloc extends Bloc<LandingEvent, LandingState> {
  LandingBloc() : super(LandingInitial()) {
    on<LandingEvent>((event, emit) {
      if (event is HomeClick) {
        emit(HomeState());
      } else if (event is LoginClick) {
        emit(LoginState());
      }
    });
  }
}

@immutable
abstract class LandingEvent extends Equatable {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class LoginClick extends LandingEvent {}

class HomeClick extends LandingEvent {}
@immutable
abstract class LandingState extends Equatable {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class LandingInitial extends LandingState {}

class LoginState extends LandingState {}

class HomeState extends LandingState {}
```

In this code, I pressed Home button from landing page, it navigate to home page. After that I closed home page. Then again I pressed home page, it is not navigate to home page. That means this code can't navigate to same page. If I go to another page then it is working. After my research I found it because of Equatable. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If we use equatable package in the bloc pattern, state must be different or state have the different value.